# How to use Font Awesome in Microsoft Office Word or PowerPoint on MacOS

Tags: microsoft-office, fonts, microsoft-powerpoint

I can use Font Awesome in Omnigraffle perfectly - paste the name of the icon and the image magically appears. The same process doesn't work with PowerPoint or Word. help!

The cheatsheet approach works but the icons on the cheatsheet are a subset of those in the icon catalogue - e.g. the browser icon doesn't exist.

OS: MacOS Big Sur Latest
Office: MacOS latest update Office 365

Comment: Thanks for moving your question here. One other point that'll help you get help:  "latest" doesn't mean much when quoting your Office/OS version. The way Office changes, "latest" as of today might be three versions out when somebody sees your question in a few months. Given the date of your post, someone energetic enough *might* take the trouble to look up current version as of 8 Feb 2021, but I wouldn't count on that. Best to quote the full version/build number for both Office and MacOS.  Sorry to be such a nag. ;-)